# How do I set up multiple observables from an event in F#?

Tags: f#, observable, reactive-programming

I'm trying to learn about the Observable module in F# by writing a program that connects to a web socket, listens for messages, and then handles them in some set of streams based on Observables.  However, I'm having a hard time understanding the actual behavior.

First, I set up a web socket like this:

```
open System
open System.Net.WebSockets
open System.Threading

let connectFeed =
    let feedUrl = "blah blah"
    let buffer : byte array = Array.zeroCreate 1024
    let segment = ArraySegment(buffer)
    let socketEvent = new Event<string>()

    let task = async {
        let random = Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond)
        use socket = new ClientWebSocket()
        let! token = Async.CancellationToken
        do! Async.AwaitTask (socket.ConnectAsync(Uri(feedUrl), token))

        while not token.IsCancellationRequested do
            let! result = Async.AwaitTask (socket.ReceiveAsync(segment, token))
            socketEvent.Trigger (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer))
            Array.fill buffer 0 buffer.Length 0uy

    }

    (task, socketEvent.Publish)

let deserializeMsg (raw:string) =
    // returns a MsgType based on the received message

let tryGetData (msg:MsgType) =
    // returns Some data for specific kind of message; None otherwise

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let feedProc, feedStream = connectFeed
    let msgStream = feedStream |> Observable.map deserializeMsg

    msgStream |> Observable.subscribe (fun m -> printfn "got msg: %A" m) |> ignore

    let dataStream = feedStream |> Observable.choose tryGetData
    dataStream |> Observable.subscribe (fun d -> printfn "got data: %A" d) |> ignore

    Async.RunSynchronously feedProc
    0
```

I'm expecting to see a printout like:

```
got msg: { some: "field" }
got msg: { some: "other" }
got msg: { some: "data" }
got data: { // whatever }
got msg: ...
...
```

Instead, only the "got msg" messages appear, even though there are messages that would cause `tryGetData` to return `Some`.

What's going on here?  How do I set up multiple `Observable` streams from a single event?

**Update**: I've updated my code with this:

```
let isMsgA msg =
    printfn "isMsgA"
    match msg with
    | MsgA -> true // where MsgA is a member of a DU defined elsewhere, and is the result of deserializeMsg
    | _ -> false

let isStringMsgA msg =
    printfn "isStringMsgA"
    if msg.StartsWith("{ \"type\": \"msga\"") then true else false

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let feedProc, feedStream = connectFeed
    let msgStream = feedStream |> Observable.map deserializeMsg

    msgStream 
    |> Observable.filter isMsgA
    |> Observable.subscribe (fun m -> printfn "got msg MsgA")
    |> ignore

    feedStream 
    |> Observable.filter isStringMsgA
    |> Observable.subscribe (fun m -> printfn "got string MsgA")
    |> ignore
```

And I get a screen full of "isStringMsgA" and "got string MsgA" messages, but exactly one each of "isMsgA" and "got msg MsgA".

I am baffled.

Here is a trimmed-down, reproducible example for anyone interesting in fiddling with it:
https://github.com/aggieben/test-observable

**Update 2**: looks like I may be seeing this behavior due to an exception being thrown in the `deserializeMsg` function.  Still digging...

Comment: I believe that `msgStream` is consuming all the events from `feedStream`, leaving none for the `dataStream` to consume. I don't know the answer yet, but I think that's the problem.

Comment: What happens if you arrange the subscriptions in reverse order? What happens if you debug-print every message from within `tryGetData`?

Answer (score 3):

I do not see any obvious reason why this should be happening - can you add some logging to `tryGetData` to check what inputs it gets and what results it returns?

When using the `Observable` module, you construct a description of the processing pipeline and `Observable.subscribe` creates a concrete chain of listeners  that do the work and attach handlers to the primary event source. However, the events do not get "consumed" - they should be sent to all the observers.

For example, try playing with the following minimal demo:

```
let evt = Event<int>()

let e1 = evt.Publish |> Observable.choose (fun n -> 
  if n % 2 = 0 then Some "woop!" else None)
let e2 = evt.Publish |> Observable.map (fun n -> n * 10)

e1 |> Observable.subscribe (printfn "E1: %s")
e2 |> Observable.subscribe (printfn "E2: %d")

evt.Trigger(1)
evt.Trigger(2)
```

If you run this, it prints the expected result:

```
E2: 10
E1: woop!
E2: 20
```

Comment: It looks like my `tryGetData` gets called once, returns `None`, and that's it.  Never gets called again.  That's not how I expected `Observable.choose` to work...

Comment: I posted a trimmed-down reproduction of the problem here: https://github.com/aggieben/test-observable